# Finding parameters for a quotient of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, T_{a,b} := \mathbb{R}[x] \ /\langle x^2+ax+b\rangle$, where $\langle x^2+ax+b\rangle$ is the ideal generated by $x^2+ax+b$.
>
> 1) for which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is $T_{a,b}$ a field?
>
> 2) for which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is $x \in T_{a,b}$ invertible ($x$ refers to the $x$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$), and how does the inverse look like?

1)

Let $b = 0 \Rightarrow T_{a,0} = \mathbb{R}[x] \ /\langle x^2+ax\rangle$.

Let $u = x, v = a x \Rightarrow u,v \in T_{a,0}$

$uv = x^2+ax \not\in T_{a,0} \Rightarrow T_{a,0}$ not field $\Rightarrow T_{a,b}$ field $\Rightarrow b \neq 0$.

This is all that I saw. Can you please tell me how the other conditions of a,b can be found, so that $T_{a,b}$ field applies? I tried to identify all roots of $x^2 + ax + b$, but didn't find an approach that helped me to go on.

2)

I tried to somehow utilize that $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ for $T_{a,b}$, but got nowhere. Can you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: The idea with the roots is good. If there are no roots, then $x^2+ax+b$ is irreducible, and the ideal generated by it maximal, hence the quotient is a field.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you, that makes sense to me. So for the root I get $x^2 + ax + b = 0 \Leftrightarrow b = 0$, so I can conclude that $T_{a,b}$ is a field for $a,b \in \mathbb{R} \Leftrightarrow b \neq 0$, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didn't succeed with the roots, can you please give me an example how to start? How do the roots look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) We  have 
$$
x(x+a)=x^2+ax=-(ax+b)+ax=-b.
$$
Thus 
$$
\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x+a}{x(x+a)}=\frac{x+a}{-b}
$$

Comment: Or divide $x^2+ax+b=0$ by $x$ and solve for $x^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks! Do I understand it correctly, that your answer means, that $x$ is invertible iff $b \neq 0$, and the inverse is $\frac{x+a}{-b}$?

Comment: I dont sure about  iff, but it works for the  if case

Comment: @Leox I tried to fully understand your question, but finally don't get it at all. Why is $a^2+ax = -(ax + b) + ax = -b$, and how do you get to $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x+1}{x(x+a)}$?

Comment: Just in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+ax+b)$ we  have that $x^2+ax+b=0$.

Comment: @Leox aah, ok, thank you!